# Is it necessary to limit a battery's current output?

Tags: batteries, current, dc, fan, load

Is it necessary to limit a battery's current output, or will the load inherently draw no more than is needed?

I have a 4S LiPo I want to connect as directly-as-possible to a DC fan of the appropriate voltage.  Do I need to add resistors to limit the current flow, or will the internal resistance of the fan ensure I don't draw more than the required current?

The 4S can deliver nearly 120 amps in burst, so I want to avoid melting/destroying things.

Comment: A fuse near battery serves as a safety device for inadvertent shorts. It adds a small amount of xx milliohm resistance but should not be significant if sized properly. If it heats up near rated current, resistance increases and heat accelerates to melt the fuse.

Comment: Any load (other than a short) will draw only what it needs to do its job, the battery/power supply is not the master, the load will attempt  to draw what it needs and the battery will try and keep up, the battery obeys the fan not the other way around. If the fan wants 0.01A, the battery will only give it 0.01A, if the fan wants 107A, the battery will (try) and give it 107A. The battery is just an energy store just like a pantry is a food store. The only thing you would need a current limiting device for is as a safety device for when things go wrong, usually with some kind of short circuit.

Comment: If the fan is rated for the battery voltage, it will draw its rated current - there is no need for additional resistors.

Comment: Not for a fan. Some LED modules or other loads may be designed to operate on a fixed current rather than a fixed voltage. But fans generally are designed to operate at a voltage or within a voltage range.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a load will draw only as much current as it "needs".  See Ohm's Law.

HOWEVER,  LiPo, batteries **ALWAYS** require load limiting and charge limiting to prevent them from catastrophic failure and danger. LiPo batteries are NOT safe or stable on their own without protective circuits around them. There are many spectacular failures related to faulty LiPo protection. This is not something to be taken casually.

Comment: I'll be charging them properly, but can you elaborate on load limiting?  I was intending to monitor the voltage to ensure it doesn't get too low - is that what you were referring to?  Or do I require additional components in my circuitry to restrict the load?